# Как отправить сообщение всем пользователям бота Telegram через Webhook

Tags: python

Как отправить сообщение всем пользователям телеграм бота, если бот работает через `Webhook`?

Comment: Подозреваю, что тебе надо где-то хранить id всех чатов, а в отправке сообщения я сложностей не вижу

Comment: Совершенно верно но реализовать не получается

Comment: я конечно не специалист по питону, но может стоит пройтись по массиву `chat.id` циклом и каждому отправить сообщение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решилось все "простым" методом! Пришлось подключать БД sqlite. Пример моего кода

```
import sqlite3

def AddUser(user_id, user_login, user_name, second_name):

# Подключаемся к SQLite
conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Обработка SQL исключений
try:
    # Выполняем SQL запрос
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_login, user_name, second_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", (user_id, user_login, user_name, second_name))
except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
    # В случаи ошибки
    print("Error:", error)

# Завершаем транзикцию
conn.commit()
# Закрываем соединение
conn.close()
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
AddUser (message.chat.id, message.chat.username, message.chat.first_name, message.chat.last_name)
```

Ну и для непосредственной отправки сообщения всем пользователям

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def key(message):

    elif message.text == 'здесь пишем команду для того что бы бот отправил сообщение все пользователям например - Реклама':
    con = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    for row in cur:
        print ('-' * 10)
        print ('user_id:', row[1])
        bot.send_message(row[1], 'Здесь сам текст который мы хотим отправить')
        print ('-' * 10)
```

Единственный минус данного способа это если кто-то решит написать боту как выше я указал "Реклама" то он соответственно запустит рекламу поэтому вижу выход только задавать какое-то значение по типу пароля. 
Если есть какие-то ваши идеи по поводу доработки скрипта предлагайте буду рад испробовать!